# What are the requirements for hosting a Call of Duty 4 Reign of the Undead server?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare, reign-of-the-undead

What are the specs I need for a hosting account to host a game server for Call of Duty 4 Reign of the Undead (COD4 ROTU)?

Specifically, I believe that the information I need to know is bandwidth requirements for hosting a 16+ person 24/7 COD4 ROTU server.

Comment: `Do not close. I really want to know this and have for several years now.` -  How badly you want to know the answer is not a reason not to close a question I'm afraid.

Comment: I've modified your question to make it more on-topic gameaddict. asking for recommendations for server hosters is considered shopping recommendation, and is therefore off-topic. Your other question, asking what the general requirements for hosting a server are, is perfectly fine.

Comment: @gameaddict Calm down. Why can't you compare the Hostgator specs to the ones mentioned in the accepted answer and use those to answer your question?

Comment: @gameaddict I'm sorry about your negative experience. It's important to realize that Wipqozn was just trying to help you out though; it's not nice to lash out at him like this.

Comment: @gameaddict from what I can see on the Hostgator website, the only 'shared service' that is apparent to me is a web hosting service. This would not be sufficient for hosting a COD4 server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several pieces of information you need to take into consideration when hosting a game server;

- How many people you want to be able to join
- The specifications required to host that many people
- The bandwidth required for that many people
- Whether the hosting solution you go for allows that kind of hosting

[This article](http://wiki.modsrepository.com/index.php/Call_of_Duty_4:_Servers) states that the system requirements for hosting a Call of Duty 4 server are similar to the requirements for hosting a Call of Duty 2 server.

**Hardware**

The following should be considered as the minimum hardware for a COD4 server (hosting a maximum of eight players):

- 1GB RAM
- 1.4+ GHz processor
- 40GB hard drive

The following server configuration would create a better hosting experience:

- 3.2GHz processor
- 8GB+ RAM
- 120GB hard drive.

The minimum hardware required to run a COD4 server is reasonable, faster hardware will only increase the user/client experience. Utilising the minimum hardware could cause frustrating lag for your users. Unlike the COD4 client version, a good video card will *not* make improvements to the performance of a dedicated COD4 server. The key hardware element when hosting COD4 is RAM.

**Networking**

COD4's requires that the following ports are open: UDP 20800, UDP 20810 and UDP 28960.

Additionally, the network connection should be heavily evaluated before beginning to host the Call of Duty server as bandwidth will be a major factor in the user experience (a lack of bandwidth can cause lag).

In this instance, you also should consider the number of users who will be connecting: more users will require more bandwidth.

For example for an eight player server (max), you should have a high-speed DSL, cable or other connection type achieving 1.5MBps down/256KBps up.

For a 32-slot COD4 server you should be aiming to have 20MBps+ down/1.5MBps+ up.

A more stable internet connection will of course provide a more solid gaming experience for those using the server.

**More reading**: [Call of Duty 4 Dedicated Server Guide](http://www.cod4boards.com/forum/showthread.php?224-Call-of-Duty-4-Dedicated-Server-Guide)

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help at all. It did not help because the original question was changed to a completely different question. So you answered his question instead of my question. I accepted the answer only because I gave up trying to ask the question I wanted.

Comment: @gameaddict, feel free to open a meta question with your concerns about the edit on your original question.

Comment: @gameaddict I answered your question directly based on your original wording in the comment on the question